# How to add elements next to other one according to an input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, nodes

using jquery or javascript.. in a comment system I need that; when I answer any comment the result must be showed exactly under the corresponding comment

I'm having problems because if I do this using the class of a container, the answer is showed under every single comment and if I use the container's id, the answer is showed always next to the first comment... So I think you could help me

Here the code I'm using...

HTML

```
<div id="comment" class="comment">
  <button class="answer-button" id="answer-button"> Answer </button>
  <input class="comment-reply" id="comment-reply" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="'.$comment_id.'">
</div>

<div id="answer-container" class="answer-container"> </div>

<form class="replyform" method="post" action="actions/responder.php">
  <input type="text" id="reply-to" name="reply" readonly="readonly" value="">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $success= '<div id="answer" class="answer">
    resulted data </div>';
?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //click answer button
      $(".answer-button").on("click", function() {
        var reply = $(".answer-button");
        //take the value of thecomment we want to answer
        var comment_id = reply.next('input#comment-reply').val();

        //now we write it in the form's input 
        document.getElementById("reply-to").value = comment_id;

        //now we go to submit the form
        $('.replyform').submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

              //once we've sent data, compare the comment and form input values
              var value = $('.replyform').find('input#reply-to').val();
              var comment = $(".answer-button").next('input#comment-reply').val();

              //if they're equal, we show the answer under the corresponding comment
              if (comment = value) {

                if (data.success) {
                  $('.replyform').slideUp();
                  $('.comment').next('.answer').html(data.text);

                } else {
                  $('.replyform').find('#result').html(data.text);
                }
              }
            }
          })
          return false;
        });
      });
```

Comment: Presumably each comment has a self id, so when you post a rely to that perhaps you now have a parent id and a self id? Assuming that is the case, you should be able to then attach the child via the parent using `.next()`? At least that's what I would try and do.

Comment: exactly! actually that's what I'm trying with                    $('.comment').next('.answer').html(data.text); but it still shows me the answer under the all comments instead of the selected one           so what I think could be a way is that if the id sent by the id of the comment container where the rely button was clicked is the same of the id sent by the form, then take that addres using jquery operators (parent, child, whatever) and use it to show the answer wher it must be but... i don't have very clear how to do that in the code

Comment: You should have the id from the database as part of the id in the container that you want to attach the child to so it would be like `<div id="comment_<?php echo $parent_id ?>">Whatever</div>` then you attach to that (which would become the parent).

Comment: ooohm okok let me try and then I'll tell you